# Time-based syncing for iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, time, client-server, synchronization

I'm trying to implement a simple sync solution to propagate a few settings between various instances of my app and my server. Changes to these settings will be infrequent and only occur on the client(s). I would like something reasonably robust without going overboard.

My strategy is to track un-synced changes on the device, and when syncing, post these to the server. The server should be able to reject a change that occurred after the previous known sync for that setting. To accomplish this, the app stores an 'Updated' date for each setting, and the server compares this to a similar field it stores for the same setting on its side. If the client's date is prior to the latest setting sync the server knows about (from a different device), the sync for that setting is rejected.

The final (hopefully) piece is to account for differences between the client and server clocks.

My initial thought is to send (alongside the updated setting), the client's current local datetime. On receipt, the server will compare the client's time to its own and know how to adjust the 'updated' timestamp on the client's setting. This sounds reasonable to me in principle, but how can I address the following two issues?

- What if the client device's clock is changed after the setting is updated by before attempting to sync it?
- Who knows how long the sync request will take to reach the server? So by the time it is received, the 'System clock' that the client provided is actually seconds or minutes out.

Comment: Read this: Synchronization with [Vector Time Pairs](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TM-650.pdf). There is no clock required, though time might optionally be used to resolve conflicts.

Comment: I've tried reading this document a couple of times previously without much sinking in, but thanks anyway. I will try again eventually. Think it might be overkill for my purposes.

Comment: I agree. It's a difficult read, but I've implemented it for syncing data between systems. Once you understand it, it's not too hard to code, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You should do everything in terms of `UTC` to avoid time zone issues. That doesn't get round the issue of the users clock just being set incorrectly so you may want to check-in to the server when data is updated to verify what the actual time is. There will be some conditions that are hard to deal with if you have no net connection. Sometimes the best you can do is to detect them and tell the user about the risk.